# use curl in shell script to substitue a variable

Tags: shell, curl

Hi i am trying to use curl in shell script as shown below but i am not able to substitute the variable $line in the CURL . please suggest

```
while read line
do
    echo "allowing mac $line"
    curl -X POST -d '{"src-mac": "$line"}' http://localhost:8080/wm/firewall/rules/json
    curl -X POST -d '{"dst-mac": "$line"}' http://localhost:8080/wm/firewall/rules/json
done < /home/floodlight/allowedmacs
```

Answer (score 7):

No variable substitution in single quotes.  Switch to double around the expansion, like this:

```
curl -X POST -d '{"src-mac": "'"$line"'"}' http://localhost:8080/wm/firewall/rules/json
curl -X POST -d '{"dst-mac": "'"$line"'"}' http://localhost:8080/wm/firewall/rules/json
```

Or you could use double-quotes around the whole thing and escape the inner ones:

```
curl -X POST -d "{\"src-mac\": \"$line\"}" http://localhost:8080/wm/firewall/rules/json
curl -X POST -d "{\"dst-mac\": \"$line\"}" http://localhost:8080/wm/firewall/rules/json
```

Either way, can't be inside single quotes when you get to `$line` if you want it expanded.

Comment: or swap the double/single quotes: `"{'src-mac': '$line'}"`

Comment: @glennjackman - nope.  While a valid literal in javascript code, that's not legal [JSON](http://www.json.org/), which requires double quotes around strings.